# How to factorize the expression $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+\sqrt{x^6}}}}$?

Tags: factoring

> How to factorize the expression $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+\sqrt{x^6}}}}\quad?$$

How to factorize the above expression? I am trying the above question by taking the above expression as $y$ and then squaring both sides. After squaring I am getting $y^2=1+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+\sqrt{ x^6}}}$. Now I shifted $1$ on the left hand side and then again squared. So, again after squaring I am getting $y^4-2y^2+1=x^2 +\sqrt{x^4+\sqrt{x^6}}$. But how to approach further. Kindly help me out with this question.

Comment: Why do you think that  this expression can be split into nontrivial factors?

Comment: What do you mean by "factorize"? Does $2\times {\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt {x^4+\sqrt{x^6}}}}\over2}$ count as a factorization?

Comment: No@Gerry Myerson

Comment: @DEBSANKARROY that only answers half of Gerry's question, though. What exactly do you have in mind when you ask for a factorization?

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.

Deb Sankar Roy, what do you mean by “factorize” ?

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+\sqrt{x^6}}}}=$$

$$=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+\left|x^3\right|}}}=$$

$$=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^2\left(x^2+\left|x\right|\right)}}}=$$

$$=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2+\left|x\right|\sqrt{x^2+\left|x\right|}}}=$$

$$=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2+\left|x\right|\sqrt{\left|x\right|\big(\left|x\right|+1\big)}}}=$$

$$=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\left|x\right|\left[\left|x\right|+\sqrt{\left|x\right|\big(\left|x\right|+1\big)}\,\right]}}\;.$$

Tell me if it is what you meant.

Comment: This should be CW.